# Put a TextView with a ScrollView between two other views (header and footer)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I would like to have a scrollable TextView / TextView inside a ScrollView.

I've already tried it myself and looked up multiple pages, however my issue always is that the text "text" TextView which says "some text" always exceeds the space between the two other Views despite getting into "ScrollMode"

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/middleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="some text"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

... 

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Updated**

[image]

Comment: The ScrollView should be a parent view, you are looking for NestedScrollView

Comment: Thanks, I that's sounds as what I am thinking about. I already saw NestedScrollView on some Google Search, but never clicked on any of the results. I will give it a try, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` property of your `TextView` also loosen the constraint property around your textview that's not appropriate. Here I have changed somewhat, which is making the textview scrollable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/middleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for your quick reply :) I was already thinking about setting height to a fixed value, however isn't there a way to have it dynamic on the users screen?

Comment: surely it's possible that's why the `ConstraintLayout` you have to know what you exactly want and set constraints according to that

Comment: Hi again, might you maybe update your solution with such a code that would keep every view on the screen and make the TextView with the large text as big as possible before switching to "ScrollMode"? I would then mark your solution as accepted, as that would then be exactly what I would like to have :)

Comment: I've already tried to do it myself, however it never worked as it should :/

Comment: your description is not clear what you want. can you draw a diagram of how things should be?

Comment: I've just added an image to the post. What I want is the TextView / ScrollView to sit with a margin of let's say 30dp below the title & 25dp above the ListView Block. I already have that with all the constraints. The only issue is that, in case the text becomes to large, the TextView's top get above the Title and ListViewBlock disappears below the screen. So, what I want is to have the text view staying with the set margin and becoming scrollable despite expanding itself